# how to call a static method in a custom magento class

Tags: php, magento, static

I have a custom model in a custom Magento model with a static function:

```
class ABC_Module_Model_ClassName
{
    static public function send ( $something)
    {
         // do something static
    }
}
```

Now I call the function like this:

```
ABC_Module_Model_ClassName::send($something); // works and is nothing wrong with it
```

More for consistency purposes, I would like to know if Mage has an internal way of calling static methods, something like this:

```
Mage::getModel('abc/module_className')::send($something); // this is wrong
// or 
Mage::getModel('abc/module_className', send($something)); // with a callback or something
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that any method like `Mage::getModel()` will actually return an instance of the class, you'll be calling it dynamically rather than statically. E.g you'd be doing `$module->staticMethod();` instead of `Module::staticMethod().`.

So your best best is to

- either put the static method as a regular function so it'll be available globally,
- put all your static methods in one class and name the class something like `Common` so you won't have to type the really long name,
- or just call it statically the way you've done in your question e.g `Module::method()`.

In the end, the only way to call a method statically is via `Class::method()`.